# JavaScript - Printing from Array of Objects Not Working

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects here that I am traversing and want to display a match if the person at the current index has an age within +/- 10 years of anyone else in the array. However, when I run it, it says "Cannot read property 'age' of undefined." Where did I go wrong?

```
function findmatches() {    
  var n = USERS.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var currName = USERS[i].firstName;
    var currAge = USERS[i].age;
    var currGender = USERS[i].gender;

    for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      if (((USERS[c].age) + 10) <= currAge) {
        document.getElementById("showmatches").innerHTML += currName + " matched to >> " + USERS[i].firstName + " " + USERS[i].lastName + " \n";
        break;
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the first for-loop inside the function "findmatches"?

Comment: Share your `USERS` array. The reason for error `Cannot read property 'age' of undefined.` is that you don't have `age` property of a user object.

Comment: Can you please share the array of object?

Comment: yes the first loop is inside the function

Comment: age is defined in the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your second `for` loop supposed to do?

In the code you posted, it iterates through first 10 users in the `USERS` array. I assume it has less users than that, so at some point `USERS[c]` is `undefined`, and you're trying to access `USERS[c].age`.

Comment: ...so the solution is replace `10` with `n`?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Also, there's plenty of useful methods available for working with arrays. For example, the whole `for` loop thing can be replaced with usage of `array.forEach()` method. You can find more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: the second for loop is to be used to go through all the elements of the array. so when i in the first loop is 0, the second for loop will go through the remainder of elements and see if a match is found. if not i in the first loop goes to index 1 and the second loop gos again to find a match etc..

Comment: So where does the number `10` in `c < 10` come from? As stated above, you should replace it with `n`.

Also since you're iterating through the same array, you should check if `i` and `c` are the equal -- if they are, skip the user in the second loop, otherwise you'll get users matched to themselves.

Comment: yeah, i made the corrections you sugested and tested some values. they are working. i have a follow up though if thats ok.

Comment: Okay, glad to help.

Comment: Thank You very much, it is greatly appreciated.